# How many 5 card hands do and don't contain the ace of clubs?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, card-games

I'm getting a bit confused here. I keep seeing two common answers for these types of situations: $51\choose5$ and $52\choose4$. Which of these answer which question? Are there $51\choose5$ hands containing the ace of clubs, or are there $52\choose4$ (or neither)?

Likewise, are there $51\choose5$ hands not containing the ace of clubs, or are there $52\choose4$?

I'm really hoping one value answers one question, and the other value answers the other question, otherwise I'll be even more confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're taking about $5$-card (perhaps poker) hands.

To get a hand without the ace of clubs, you need to choose $5$ from the other $51$ cards, and there are $\binom{51}5$ ways to do that.

To get a hand with the ace of clubs, you need to choose the remaining $4$ cards from the other $51$ cards, and there are $\binom{51}4$ ways to do that.

The sum is $\binom{51}5+\binom{51}4=\binom{52}5$, as it must be.

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you very much! The exertion of pascals identity helped a lot, that's exactly what was causing my confusion: the numbers I had weren't adding up to $52\choose5$. Thank you again!